# How to config prebid's s2s on self hosted server?

Tags: prebid.js, adexchange

1. Account id is required field in s2s config, how to get it for
   the self-hosted server.
2. How to set up the self-hosted server for prebid, will it be normal js 
   file which can be hosted in firebase or any prerequisites are needed for it?
3. If yes, what are they? and how will they effect endpoint url?

Answer (score 0):

**2)** The server setup is detailed in the [Readme on Prebid Server Github](https://github.com/prebid/prebid-server/blob/master/README.md). This would be a standalone server that takes requests from prebid.js

In Prebid.js you'd specify a different endpoint:

```
pbjs.setConfig({
    s2sConfig: {
        adapter: 'prebidServer',
        endpoint: 'https://prebid.adnxs.com/pbs/v1/auction',
    }
})
```

(Not sure if you'd need to use a different adaptor or not)

**1)** Since you're hosting this you could in theory build it without that account id as a requirement. (not sure where in the codebase this exactly is used beyond user logins to the hosted Prebid Server version